# How to use NSLineBreakByCharWrapping with setNumberOfLines:1 on iOS?

Tags: ios, uilabel, word-wrap

For example, if the text for a `UILabel` is: `"Questions that may already have your answer"`, I want it to print 
`"Questions that may alr"`. I don't want to clip the last character but cut the text at that point.

I cannot use a character limit as most fonts are not monospaced. I cannot use clipping as It may cut the text at another point or it may cut that last letter "r" from any where of it.

The behaviour I want is similar to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` while `numberOfLines = 0`.

So, I want it to drop(wrap) that non-fitting last character but I want it to drop/wrap to a hidden space = I don't want that second line.

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

To get required output you need to know width of the label, which can be known by following method:

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}]; // iOS 7 and later

CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]]; // prior to iOS 7
```

- set the size of your label with the above calculated size.
- set the numberOfLines property to 1;
- set the lineBreakMode property to NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

  ```
  UILabel *yourLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, size.width, 50)];
  placeLbl.numberOfLines = 1;
  placeLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
  ```

Comment: The problem is, the text is not a fixed text, so I cannot just calculate the size. We need something like "determining maximum number of characters that can fit into the targeted space. After that, we can just get substring accordingly. So I don't know what to try other than trying to find the appropriate number of characters those takes enough space in a loop. (Like `for(int i=0;i<...;i++){ maxIndex= i; if(size.width of (substring of string to i)> targeted width){break;} }` But this doesn't seem efficient)

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3.0

```
labelObject.numberOfLines = 0;
labelObject.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byCharWrapping
```